# How to ignore empty array collection in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, collections, laravel-5

Hi I am trying to fetch related data from relation in laravel 5.1 and it return me an empty array collection. How will Ignore the empty array collection from my variable in laravel.

```
 $brandsId = Input::has('brands') ? Input::get('brands') : null;
   $brands = Brand::findMany($brandsId);
   foreach($brands as $brand){
        $products = $brand->products()->paginate(15)//this will return an empty array if it doesnt find aything;
         echo "<pre>";
         print_r( $products);
```

The empty array collction looks like this.

```
Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator Object
(
    [total:protected] => 0
    [lastPage:protected] => 0
    [items:protected] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
        (
            [items:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [currentPage:protected] => 1
    [path:protected] => http://localhost:8000/filter
    [query:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [fragment:protected] => 
    [pageName:protected] => page
)
```

Comment: you could always check whether it is empty or not using `count($product)` function. beyond that, i can't help - if i assume that you're trying to render it in a view (or put non-empty result to something else) all non-empty result then you'll have to check is it empty or not manually.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [isEmpty()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-isempty)

> The isEmpty method returns true if the collection is empty; otherwise,
>   false is returned:

```
if ($products->isEmpty()) echo "collection is empty"
```

in the docs for collection you will [see all available functions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#available-methods)